Cranes operating on 433 MHz remotes experience shutdown
I have in operation multiple cranes with hoists and bridges.
The system seems to experience single hoist shutdown when two remotes on 433 MHz operate together. There are six remotes available. The hoist shutdown is randomized.
The six remotes can access 6 receivers in the air. The vendor is perplexed by these actions.
Reprogramming of the remotes by the vendor has not repaired the condition.
It has been suggested that RF Burst interference can be the culprit. 120 V/60 Hz powers the receivers on the crane/hoists above the working floor.
Any suggestions or insight?

that behavior makes complete sense ... a hoist should always stop when it receives conflicting commands

this site is not a brainstorming forum ... it is a Q&A site ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

suggestions or insight: get somebody to perform a health and safety assessment of using hoists controlled by RF.

Hi there. I have extensive experience from designing these very types of remote control systems. There are many things that could be causing your problem: other transmitters, EMI, too wide band allocation of each system, conducted emissions from supply or other sources etc etc. As such, this question is a little bit broad for the Q&A format, but I'm happy to help you out if you poke me in the chat.

Another problem that I've sometimes encountered for these type of installations when you have lots of radios sharing the same space, is that the carrier of one system might end up on another system's image frequency, which is always a weak spot even if there is decent image rejection calibration in place. Which may not necessarily be the case if you are using one of the cheaper brands. A serious vendor will help you out when making frequency planning of the plant, to prevent things like this.

Actually... 120VAC/60Hz... does that mean North America? 433MHz is not a public, license-free band there. You may be facing interference from someone who has the legal rights by FCC etc to transmit on the frequency while you haven't. This applies to license free use in USA and Canada: FCC part 15


The vendor is perplexed by these actions.

TL;DR: The vendor doesn't have the competence necessary to make those machines.
You'll need a consultant electrical engineer who will do the vendor's job just so that your plant can keep running. This potentially means using more robust RF remote control modules - they exist, and they cost good money, but they are designed to keep heavy machinery safe to operate.
The most likely explanation for the shutdowns is that if the controller receives too many corrupt packets, it shuts down. This is a reasonable response in single-remote systems with unsophisticated over-the-air protocols. The vendor likely used low-cost RF modules entirely unsuitable for the task.
For multi-remote systems, the encoding of the packets must be robust so that the probability of interpreting a corrupt packet as a valid packet is low enough. That's because each additional remote is a potential intentional interference source. So interference isn't a random background event, but a systematic problem. Then a hoist can keep running, although there still needs to be a timeout. If only bad packets are received for a long time, there's a good chance that the remote itself is broken, and the hoist would be operating without control.
The best solution would be to use different RF modules for the remotes and the receivers, that support sharing of the medium without corrupting data, and are meant for industrial applications. Expect to spend $20k+ on this project if you get an engineer who is familiar with RF controls of cranes and can implement them quickly. Local circumstances will vary of course.
There are some workarounds that could be low cost (without replacing hardware), by modifying the firmware on the remotes to lower the probability of on-air collisions, and to make the receiver firmware more robust. It seems like you're already operating in an unregulated market with ad-hoc industrial solutions that are dangerous. So one more "band-aid" on an already poorly designed system may not be out of the question. How much value do you place on the human life and product in this operation?
There is a chance that I'm totally off-base and this whole thing happened in, say, Germany, with a major industrial controls vendor. It's not unthinkable. But not terribly likely.

Ahem, I might be working for a company just like that. The serious, rugged flavour of remotes for sure. There's some 20-30 different brands world-wide and most of them do all the things you mention here. It would have to be some very cheap brand not to. But even quality brands will do you no good if there's flaws in the frequency planning or external devices also operating at 433MHz. It's an open, license free band in many countries around the world.

As for $20k+ not necessarily. 6 systems do cost a little bit, but plain on/off hoists are simple enough. Overhead cranes that travel are more complex and involve controlling of different motions and speeds.

@Lundin I imagine that the remotes have an active mode where they transmit on some schedule so that the receiver can be assured that the remote is present and well. I also imagine that most certified systems will deal with multiple remotes of the same kind gracefully - it's a low-bandwidth human-interface system and getting a shared medium then is not too hard, with many possible solutions you're aware of. It looks to me like OP is dealing with some home-brew solution that's hair-rising to even think oif.

@Lundin That'd be the cost of the hardware, getting an engineer on-site, doing the hardware modifications, documenting them, etc. Lots of hours even if fundamentally it's a simple job. Maybe I'm over-estimating a bit. If a serious engineer gets to work on such an apparent boondoggle to fix it, they'd need a lot of CYA documentation not to be blamed for accidents that are likely to arise due to procedural/systemic issues in such places... It'd be bad news if they got stopped at the border next time because someone died and blame's on them...

Any seriously designed system sends continuously over narrowband FM/FSK. They each have their own unique identifier sent with the radio protocol and verified by the receiver, to prevent accidental activation of the wrong crane, which would obviously be wildly non-compliant.

And yeah doing the actual installation job is another story but there's usually technicians from the crane vendor who are used to doing that.

@Lundin Of course. But I imagine that OP is dealing with some boondoggle that's under-documented and the sheer effort of dealing with this remotely through technicians would be potentially no savings. I am perhaps a pessimist and assume a scenario much worse than it is. There's plenty of YouTube videos where people in the industry proudly show their homebrew remote control systems for overhead cranes and it's rather distressing to watch. It may just be a misconfiguration of a decent system in a well regulated place. Hopefully.

I just realized that 120VAC/60Hz might be a strong indication that this is in North America and they should probably not be using 433MHz then. It might be Central or South America though, where restrictions are different depending on which country we're talking about.
